# How send json on body by http post request?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, afnetworking-2

I tried to send a json on my server on body via http post method i use Afnetworking but it isn't it response error it it server side problem or http post request problrm

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"username": @"hasanProj",
                             @"password" : @"123321",
                             @"email" : @"17.chayon@gmail.com",
                             @"firstName":@"chayon",
                             @"lastName":@"ahmed"
                             };
     NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonStr);
    NSLog(@"%@",parameters);

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testgcride.com:8081/v1/users"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        //NSString *jsonString = [self getJSONStringWithDictionary:parameters];
    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager= [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"moinsam" password:@"cheese"];
    //manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
     manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
    [manager POST:@"http://testgcride.com:8081/v1/users" parameters:jsonStr success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: JSON: {
    detail = "Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@bc6c187c";
    developerMessage = "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException";
    errors =     {
    };
    status = 400;
    timeStamp = 1445168467370;
    title = "Message Not Readable";
}

Comment: Looks like you are sending rubbish to the server